# Control a 120 Vac relay with a triac. Good idea?

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, triac

I'm beginning the design of a light control system based on a microcontroller.

This is to activate the lights, what is usually used are continuous voltage relays, in ranges of 5, 12 or up to 24 VDC.

These relays are activated by the microcontroller through a transistor.

Now, we have the option of acquiring 120 Vac relays similar to [RTD34615](https://www.mouser.ec/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity/RTD34615?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtGt%252Bn33CgIPz5XOOZlHMpoUMD8yoPMz08%3D).

To activate these AC relays with the microcontroller, I plan to use a circuit similar to the following, using an opto-triac to activate the relays.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYLTyJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can this electrical design have any problem or drawback?

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Or you could just drive the relay coil from DC.

Comment: The relays that a manufacturer is offering us can only operate with 120VAC

Comment: Well then you have little choice than to go with what you proposed. Note that the TRIAC will latch on and cannot be used to interrupt current. It will only turn off at the next AC zero cross after the gate signal is removed, but relays are so slow it won't matter.

Comment: An Opto triac can easily drive a power Triac, which may be best

Comment: @FabiánRomo I use the MOC302x and MOC306x devices to drive 40 A relays just as you suggest, using shaded AC relays whose coils are designed to operate directly from mains AC voltages. Works fine.

Comment: @jonk

Thank you very much, what you have answered may be the answer to my question.

Comment: @FabiánRomo [Here is a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWMwZ.png) of something I did a long while ago using the MOC series devices I mentioned with a 40 A relay, for validation and testing then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with the opto-triac, given a 120VAC coil, however I would  use the 600V version of the opto-triac and add an RC snubber across the triac.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. Should a RC snubber also go in parallel to the inductor coil?

Comment: You only need one, and across the triac makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> *Now, we have the option of acquiring 120 Vac relays similar to
> RTD34615.*

I think you mean RT314615 (115 V AC coil with approximately 250 mH inductance).

> *Can this electrical design have any problem or drawback?*

None that I can see other than a little nit picking...

If you can live with a several millisecond delay due to the opto-triac remaining on until the end of the AC mains cycle then it shouldn't be a big deal. Also, the triac in the opto-triac won't be as efficient as an opto MOSFET such as this ([below](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TLP3558AF?qs=r5DSvlrkXmLolvaAE4UvXg==)) and, that inefficiency might cause the triac to get a little hot. But, on the other hand, using a triac means that the back emf on an inductive relay coil load will be smaller when the triac commutates into the off condition. Nit picking really!

[image]

> *Any comment or suggestion is welcome*

I've tried!

Comment: The problem is that the end user can connect any type of lamp (incandescent, fluorescent, led lamp, etc) and I'm not sure if that device that you mention works correctly. An electromechanical relay is more reliable than a "solid" relay

Comment: @Andyaka - Hi, Please add the link to that datasheet. Thanks :-)

Comment: @SamGibson the link has been added but, I thought we'd had this discussion before about data sheets; I'm doing Toshiba a favour by pointing their stuff out so they're highly unlikely to quibble over me extracting a section of their data sheet and posting it here. Isn't that the real point - it says "Toshiba" on the picture and the part numbers are clearly stated on the picture hence, anyone with only 25% of their brain currently active could easily track down the original data sheet from the info in the picture.

Comment: @FabiánRomo I'm not suggesting he gets rid of the mechanical relay. Having said that my answer is a little ambiguous so I'll fix that.

Comment: @Andyaka - I don't think we finished the previous discussion & I'm sorry if I gave you false hope of not having to follow that site rule. [The requirement for a reference link to the original source for any resource used in an answer](/help/referencing) is a Stack Exchange-wide rule. There is no exemption for a claim of doing someone a favour and there is no discussion - it's an SE-wide rule requiring the author of an answer to supply a link to the source of any external resources incorporated therein. It doesn't matter how easy or hard it would be for someone to track down the source. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson OK, cleared up I suppose.